# The probability that a killed random walk on $[-N,N]$ escapes before dying

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

Let $X_t$ be a continuous time simple random walk in $\mathbb{Z}$ starting at $0$, let $\tau^*$ be an exponential r.v of parameter $1$. What is the probability 
$$
  \mathbb{P}(\tau ^* \ge \tau_{N})?
$$
Where $\tau_N = \inf \{t \in \mathbb{R}: X_t \in \{-N,N\} \}$.

My first attempt was to use the optional stopping theorem, but it didn't seem to be enough to extract the probability I am interested in.

**EDIT:** If an analytical representation is not possible, is there asymptotics as $N \to \infty.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_n$ denote the probability of escape before being killed when started from $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. We are interested in the value of $p_0$. By the memoryless property of the exponential distribution, conditioning on the first step we get
\begin{equation}
p_0 = \frac 13 p_1 + \frac 13 p_{-1}. 
\end{equation}
More generally, for $-N + 1 \leq i \leq N-1$ we have
\begin{equation}
p_i = \frac 13 p_{i+1} + \frac 13 p_{i-1}
\end{equation}
with boundary conditions $p_N = p_{-N} = 1$. Solving this difference equation we get
\begin{equation}
p_n = \frac{\psi^n + \psi^{-n}}{\psi^N + \psi^{-N}} = \frac{\cosh(n \log \psi)}{\cosh(N \log \psi)}. 
\end{equation}
where $\psi = \frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$. In particular, for $n=0$ we obtain
\begin{equation}
p_0 = \frac{1}{\cosh(N \log \psi)}. 
\end{equation}